# Android Jetpack Compose cannot change BasicTextField cursor thumb color

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, textfield, android-compose-textfield

Currently I'm working with android jetpack compose BasicTextField. And when I change cursor color, I expect the cursor handle to be changed with the same color as well. But it turns out with a different color. Is this a bug or I did set something wrong?

Here is what I have set

```
colors = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors(
    backgroundColor = Color.Transparent,
    focusedIndicatorColor = colorResource(id = R.color.accent),
    unfocusedIndicatorColor = colorResource(id = R.color.lightest_grey),
    focusedLabelColor = colorResource(id = R.color.secondary_20),
    unfocusedLabelColor = colorResource(id = R.color.light_grey),
    textColor = colorResource(id = R.color.secondary),
    cursorColor = colorResource(id = R.color.secondary),
  )
```

[image]

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You have to provide a custom **`TextSelectionColors`**.

Something like:

```
val customTextSelectionColors = TextSelectionColors(
    handleColor = Green,
    backgroundColor = Red
)

CompositionLocalProvider(LocalTextSelectionColors provides customTextSelectionColors) {
    BasicTextField(
        value = text,
        onValueChange = {text = it},
        cursorBrush = SolidColor(Black)
    )
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: This works fine for light mode, but for some reason , the handles and text cursor is not visible on darkmode, any idea why?